# Is deloading useful for recovering?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, health, bench-press, tendons

I think I'm I have a tendon or ligament à bit hurted at the bottom left side of my left chest because for 1 month I've rushed at weights (I've increased it to fast).

Should I decrease the weight and the number of reps performed within a week at each exercise (it's called Deloading)?

Answer (score 2):

Deloading is excellent for nervous system, and recovering the body as a whole between 6-8 week spouts of constant weightlifting. its 9-14 days of not lifting, or halving the weight used. As a recovery tool on it's own, if you're injured or have a bad tendon (due to whatever), the quickest way to recover is to leave it alone, which would include removing any and all exercises that use your chest muscle. Continued use will only aggravate the tendon and increase the time it takes to recover. If you want to recover  the quickest, take a week or more off until the pain goes away, then start out with really light weights to ease the muscle back into weightlifting. If you keep doing what you're doing, your body will naturally "deload" and reduce the weights used on all your horizontal pushing exercises until you eventually recover or your tendon gets worse and forces you to take a couple months off entirely. one or two weeks is much better than 6-8 weeks off.